# Any existing sample for http json service

Tags: java, json, http, sample

I am trying to implement a server that processes the request from an Iphone app. Basically I plan to use json format with http protocol. I believe there must be some existing sample/project that I could use rather than from scratch.
Could anyone please give some sample links.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Google for REST tutorial. There are more samples out there than you can shake a stick at, but you have to restrict your question: what server side technology/language do you plan to use (java, .net, python, php, ruby, turbo basic ...)

Comment: Hi, I plan to use java to implement this. I am trying to find a sample project with the setting (like xml config) as well. So I could start with it.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [this](http://moca.googlecode.com/svn-history/r899/servers/openmrs-modules/rest/branches/gsocnewbranch/web/src/org/openmrs/module/restmodule/web/RestServlet.java) link which shows a Servlet which responds with either XML or JSON reponse.

In order to create the JSON look at [this](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/263-how-to-generate-json-from-java/) post.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could you please help to give the whole java project instead of the single java file?